# Why is window.close() not working if open() works?

Tags: javascript, html, window

I'm working on a big JavaScript project and I have this function in which I open a window and then close it using inputs in a form.

The problem is that, when I try to close the window I've already opened, it doesn't work.

This are my files:

index.html :

```
...
      <section id="seccion5" class="section">
        <h2>Responsive tester</h2>
        <form id="responsive-tester">
          <input type="url" name="direccion" placeholder="URL" required>
          <br><br>
          <input type="text" name="ancho" placeholder="Ancho" required>
          <br><br>
          <input type="text" name="alto" placeholder="Alto" required>
          <br><br>
          <input type="submit" name="probar" value="Probar">
          <input type="button" name="cerrar" value="Cerrar">
        </form>
      </section>
...
```

index_dom.js :

```
...
import responsiveTester from "./prueba_responsive.js";

const d = document;

d.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", (e) => {
  ...
  responsiveTester("responsive-tester");
});
```

prueba_responsive.js :

```
const d = document;

export default function responsiveTester(form) {
  const $form = d.getElementById(form);
  let tester;

  d.addEventListener("submit", (e) => {
    if (e.target === $form) {
      // o (e.target.matches($form))
      e.preventDefault();
      tester = window.open(
        $form.direccion.value,
        "tester",
        `innerWidth=${$form.ancho.value}, innerHeight=${$form.alto.value}`
      );
    }
  });

  d.addEventListener("click", (e) => {
    if (e.target.name === "cerrar" && tester) {
      // Comprueba el atributo 'name' del botón
      console.log("Función CERRAR activada");
      tester.close();
    }
  });
}
```

I've tried changing the place where I declare the variable `tester`. I've also tried writing a verification message in the second event listener. While it does show this message, it still doesn't work.

Comment: what is the runtime value of `$form.direccion.value`?

Comment: I tried putting the following values: "https://youtu.be/WHfyN411fd4?list=PLvq-jIkSeTUZ6QgYYO3MwG9EMqC-KoLXA", 720, 120. I don't know if that's what you meant, let me know if I misunderstood

Comment: cool then this is because it violates "same-origin" policy. `window.open()` returns a `WindowProxy`, not a true `Window` object. That proxy ensure the "same-origin" policy. Read more here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/open

Comment: Tysm, I would've never found out. If it's not much asking for, could you explain to me how can I solve this? I've read the link you attached, but I didn't understand a thing (started learning JavaScript just 3 weeks ago). Again, thank you, you're amazing
Edit: i've tried using a different URL and it's working fine; I now understand the problem so there's no need for an explanation. Tysm for your time :)

Comment: no worries, I don't discriminate against new people. welcome to javascript world. For short, your domain currently is `localhost`, the new window you open is `youtube[dot]com`. That is not "same origin" (a.k.a not the same domain). This is natively implemented by the browser, so you have no choice except obey it. A proxy is like a clone which has all features of its origin. However, a proxy can be injected with modification. The `WindowProxy` is just a built-in proxy object provided by browser. In your case, it prevents your `close()` if not the same origin.

Comment: Further restrictions are place on window/tabs opened in script from a different origin, preventing any or perhaps very limited access between the two windows. See docs for [Window.opener](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Windowopener) for more details.